# How to prove the correlation between two variables using covariance

Tags: correlation, self-study, covariance

If two variables are related in this way,

$y=a+bx$

How to prove that these variables are perfectly correlated(correlation coefficient of 1) using covariance?

Need some guidance to start..

Comment: They are perfectly correlated by the invariance property of correlation (second paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Mathematical_properties)). The answer by @IMA provides the computational details.

Comment: (1) Presumably the "variables" are $y$ and $x$; $a$ and $b$ are intended to be constants. (Otherwise, the conclusion may be incorrect.) (2) Proofs are sequences of statements proceeding by deductive rules from *assumptions* to conclusions. You tell us the desired conclusion, but what assumptions are available to you? In particular, *what is your definition of correlation?* One of the best is that it's the expectation of the product of the *standardized* variables. Starting from this, the proof becomes obvious because the linear transformation $x\to ax+b$ does not change the standardized value.

Comment: I had also better remark that any demonstration of this result--including the three proposed so far (in a comment and in two answers) is necessarily invalid! As a counterexample, consider the case $a=0, b=-1$: $x$ and $y$ are perfectly *anticorrelated* with coefficient $-1$, not $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one above is right but it seems kind of strange to prove it via a linear model including assumptions. I think it is a bit easier still:
$$
Cov(x,y) = Cov(x,a+bx) = bCov(x,x) = b Var(x) $$
Which gives us for the correlation with $y=a+bx$ so $V(y) = V(a+bx)$:
$$
cor(x,y) = \frac{bV(x)}{\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(a+bx)}}\\
$$ And because the properties of variance, $a$ is out and $b$ is squared:$$
= \frac{bV(x)}{\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{b^2V(x)}} \\
$$ Now it's just fractions$$
= \frac{bV(x)}{\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{b^2}} \\
= \frac{bV(x)}{\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(x)}|b|} \\
= \frac{bV(x)}{|b|V(x)} \\
=\pm 1
$$

Important here is just to use the rules of variances. No need to assume a model or error term. Another way to think of this is that the correlation shows the linear relationship. If these variables are related like in the formula, they are obviously perfectly linear dependent and correlation must be 1

Comment: The question is tagged as [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), so the answer is probably too detailed in the first instance.

Comment: @Quantlbex It's so detailed, in fact, that it's wrong.  (The error occurs in replacing $\sqrt{b^2}$ with $b$.)

Answer (score 3):

Start with an econometric model (including error term $e$)

$y=a+bx+e$

$cov(y,x)=cov(a+bx+e,x)=cov(a,x)+cov(bx,x)+cov(e,x)=0+bvar(x)+0$

So, $cov(y,x)=bvar(x)$

or, $b=cov(y,x)/var(x)$

but, we know that $cov(y,x)=cor(x,y)*sd(y)*sd(x)$

so, $b=cor(x,y)*sd(y)/sd(x)$

If $cor(x,y)=1$ (perfect positive correlation):

$b=sd(y)/sd(x)$

If $cor(x,y)=-1$ (perfect negative correlation):

$b=-sd(y)/sd(x)$

Note: by exogenity assumption, $cov(e,x)=0$, $sd()$ means standard deviation, $var()$ means variance, $cov()$ means covariance, and $cor()$ means correlation.

Comment: what is the significance of b=sd(y)/sd(x)?

Comment: under that condition you will have two variables perfectly correlated. That is what you asked for, I think.

Comment: am i right to say that since sd(y)/sd(x) will be greater than zero, b will also be greater than zero.

Comment: The question is tagged as [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), so the answer is probably too detailed in the first instance.

Comment: This entire exposition is mystifying. I believe the question concerns the correlation of $x$ and $a + bx$. In particular it does not ask to solve for $b$.

Comment: @whuber: In absence of any further information, it is hard to see whether OP is talking of mathematical model or an econometric model; the derivation of $b$ is the condition under which two variables are perfectly correlated in a linear model.

Comment: But you are not answering the question, regardless of lack of information! I think you go right off the rails in an entirely unexpected direction as soon as you introduce a random variable ($e$) that clearly was not part of the question. At a minimum, you should be explicit about your interpretation of the question so that others will be able to appreciate your answer.

Comment: @lakesh: if you are assuming perfect positive correlation, b will be always positive while for perfect negative correlation, it is always negative; this is because `sd(x)` and `sd(y)` are positive numbers(ignoring the case of zero situation here.